# using annotation builder in extended zend form class

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form, zend-framework2

i was reading http://mwop.net/blog/2012-07-02-zf2-beta5-forms.html and working with that annotation builder in zf2 and doctrine without any problem

i wonder if i had a zend form class ... for example  class bookForm ...  how can i use this annotation builder inside the class

for example load basic fields from doctrine entity annotation then add some extra things (like submit button) inside the bookForm class ...

in mwop.net example it use within controller  ... if I add my extra form fields in that controller would be too ugly..

```
use MyVendor\Model\User;
use Zend\Form\Annotation\AnnotationBuilder;

$user    = new User();
$builder = new AnnotationBuilder();
$form    = $builder->createForm($user);

$form->bind($user);
$form->setData($dataFromSomewhere);
if ($form->isValid()) {
    // $user is now populated!
    echo $form->username;
    return;
} else {
    // probably need to render the form now.
}
```

please help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found this question while trying to find a way of adding fieldsets using the AnnotationBuilder. The correct way to add fieldsets would be to set the Annotation\Type in your entity like so

```
namespace Application\Entity;
/** 
 * 
 * My Entity.
 * 
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="my_table")
 * 
 * @Annotation\Name("my_name")
 * @Annotation\Type("fieldset")
 * 
 */
class SomeEntity ...
```

Then within your form you are able to add the Annotated form as a fieldset like so

```
namespace Application\Form;

use Zend\Form\Form,
    Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManager,
    DoctrineModule\Stdlib\Hydrator\DoctrineObject as DoctrineHydrator,
    Zend\Form\Annotation\AnnotationBuilder;

class SomeForm extends Form
{
    public function __construct(ObjectManager $objectManager)
    {
        // we want to ignore the name passed
        parent::__construct('entity-create-form');
        $this->setAttribute('method', 'post')
             ->setHydrator(new DoctrineHydrator($objectManager));

        $builder    = new AnnotationBuilder();

        $entity = new Application\Entity\SomeEntity;
        //Add the fieldset, and set it as the base fieldset
        $fieldset = $builder->createForm( $entity ) ;
        $fieldset->setUseAsBaseFieldset(true);
        //var_dump($fieldset);
        $this->add( $fieldset );


        $this->add(array(
            'type' => 'Zend\Form\Element\Csrf',
            'name' => 'csrf'
        ));

        $this->add(array(
            'name' => 'submit',
            'attributes' => array(
                'type' => 'submit',
                'value' => 'Save'
            )
        ));
    }
}
```

Hope this helps someone else.

Comment: at the time i posted the solution there was no @annotation/type ... its added recently to zf2 package

Comment: Yes I have seen this was a late addition to the framework, your answer actually helped me to solve a separate issue with injecting doctrine hydrator into base forms which is still a challenge with the Annotation builder. This answer is only to help for those still trying to find out how to handle such tasks

Answer (score 2):

You can set the base form class in your entity class like

```
/**
 * @Annotation\Type("App\Form\BookForm")
 */
class Model
{
}
```

Full working example: https://gist.github.com/nepda/d572f9ad787c48c8555d

Answer (score 1):

actually for my issue you have to create your own base form using zend_form 2.0  then add the
secondary form that u build with AnnotationBuilder as field-set to first form

code example :

```
$newform = new BaseForm();


        $user = new Entity\Material;
        $builder = new AnnotationBuilder();
        $form = $builder->createForm($user);
        $fld = $form->getElements();
        foreach ($fld as $fldone) {
            $newform->add($fldone);
        }
```