# Zend Framework 2 - Annotation Forms and Fieldsets

Tags: php, zend-form, zend-framework2, fieldset

I've got the following problem: I read [this](https://packages.zendframework.com/docs/latest/manual/en/modules/zend.form.quick-start.html#using-annotations) doc about `AnnotationForms`. It works great so far. The thing is that I now need to add a `CSRF-Token` and a `Submit-Button`.

The doc says that I should use a `FieldSet`. But in the [docs to FieldSets](https://packages.zendframework.com/docs/latest/manual/en/modules/zend.form.collections.html#creating-fieldsets) they only describe how to include it in a regualr `Zend\Form`. But all my form definition lies within the Entity.php...because its an AnnotationForm.

Could anybody tell me how to get this token and my button into my AnnotationForm?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, first you create the form via the `AnnotationBuilder` and then you manually add your stuff.

```
$form = $builder->createForm('User');
$form->add(new \Zend\Form\Element\Csrf('security'));
```

and so on... ;)

Alternatively, since you'd want some order you'd build a Form, add the `csrf` and the `submit` as well as a `fieldset`. Then to the add the annotation form INTO the Fieldset.

Comment: Sounds like a good solution. Could you provide a code example of how to do this? Would be great!

Comment: I'd love to, but quite honestly the time is lacking, last work day and due dates. This blog may help though: http://www.michaelgallego.fr/blog/?p=190

Answer (score 0):

While a relatively old question I was still finding it hard to find a 'correct' way to add fieldsets with the AnnotationBuilder.

[See my previous stack answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18427685/533585) on how you are able to add entities as an instance of Zend\Form\Fieldset rather than an instance of Zend\Form